# Identify which state the user belongs to out of the 50 states in United States of America - without asking for other permissions than internet access

Tags: android, ios, ip-address, sim-card, country-codes

We are currently using the SIM card/Network to find out which country we should relate the user to. This enables us to have different business logic in different countries.

We now have a requirement to have different business logic depending on which state (e.g California, or Texas etc.) the user "belongs" to. Our thought is that the first time the user opens the app, it will (in the background) determine which state the user "belongs" to.

1. Can we do that without making a request to a server e.g. is this information for instance contained on the SIM card or in some other place where we can access it?
2. In what other ways would you suggest this to be done?

Thank you for all the help you can give.

Comment: Don't know the answer to the first question, for the second one though you can use https://developer.akamai.com/edgescape or a similar service.

Comment: Thanks @AnkurKesharwani. We are definitely more interested in the first option, if it is possible, but if not IP -> geo-location might be a good option.